Decision making dilemma
How to stay with a decision, I get confusion after I take a decision. I think all the possibilities of them and can't take any one. What are the techniques to make clear decision?

Welcome. We are unable to provide personalized diagnosis or advice on medical or psychological matters. If you are concerned then you should seek the advice of a professional near you.
